# How thread.join() works?

Tags: c++, operating-system, synchronization, pthreads

I am having trouble understanding `thread.join();`

I have surfed the documentations for explanation but of no avail. The following program is a part of our assignment and simulates the Petersons solution using pthreads.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>

using namespace std;

bool flag[2];
char turn;

mutex mux1;
mutex mux2;

void first(int num)
{
  flag[0] = true;
  turn = 'j';

  while ( turn == 'j' && flag[1] == true )
  ;

  mux1.lock();
  cout<<" in critical section of i with thread number "<<num<<endl;
  mux1.unlock();

  flag[0] = false;
 }

void second(int num)
{
  flag[1] = true;
  turn = 'i';

  while ( turn == 'i' && flag[0] == true )
  ;

  mux2.lock();
  cout<<" in critical section of j with thread number "<<num<<endl;
  mux2.unlock();

  flag[1] = false;
 }

 int main()
 {
  thread k[3];
  thread j[3];

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   j[i] = thread(second,i);

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   k[i] = thread(first,i);

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
   j[i].join();
   k[i].join();
  }

 return 0;
 }
```

The question that I particularly have is:

The following line from cppreference for thread.join()

> Blocks the current thread until the thread identified by *this finishes its execution.
>
> The completion of the thread identified by *this synchronizes with the corresponding successful return from join().

Which thread is *this here? , and how multiple joined threads execute and in what order?

It will be quite intuitive if the explanation can be provided with reference to the code.

Comment: for `j[i].join();` the `this` is thread handle in vector `j` at position `i`. To simplify this `some_thread_handle.join()` join refers to `some_thread_handle` that was previously created with `some_thread_handle = thread(args...)`

Answer (score 2):

*this is a pointer referring to the actual thread handling the threads you are working on

e.g. if you do

```
main(){
    std::thread foo(x);
    foo.join();
}
```

then the thread owning the main function will be blocked until foo is done!

Comment: I understand that main is blocked until foo finishes. However, if you say that *this is associated to main, then according to the cpp-reference statement it should be that, foo is blocked until main finishes it's execution.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer for the first part of your question... for the second part

> [...] how multiple joined threads execute and in what order?

Once joined the thread does not execute anymore, because `join` blocks until the thread finishes its execution. If you dont implement dedicated measures, you dont know in what order threads execute and even if you have

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

it might be that `t2` finishes before `t1`, but your program will first wait for `t1` to finish and only then for `t2`.

Comment: I had some trouble understanding this. If I write t1.join(), which thread is blocked, t1 or main?

Comment: the one calling `t1.join`. In other words, `t1.join` only returns after `t1` finished execution. Think of it as an equivalent to `thread::join(){ while( still executing){} return;}`

Comment: So it means that if we join threads in main, then the thread controlling main initiates the call and is blocked until the joined threads are through with their execution, right?